# npm install from a git repository not working

Tags: node.js, git, npm, npm-install

I am trying to install modules hosted on github using `npm install`.
For example

```
npm install git+https://github.com/balderdashy/enpeem.git
```

But this is not placing the module in the `node_modules` folder.
If I run with `--verbose` flag, I can see that the module is getting fetched and going to `appData` folder.

> node -v v4.6.1
>
> npm -v  2.15.9

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try to use the command `npm install enpeem --save` instead

Comment: Works for me with Node v6.5.0

Comment: Worked after updating node to v6.9.0.

Comment: Rather than post your solution as a [comment](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), please [post an answer to your own question](//stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). This makes it easier for other users to find the answer, and to see that your problem has been solved. (You will be able to [accept](//stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) your answer after a couple days.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating node to v6.9.0 solved the problem.